# Zend framework sql injecttion and XSS protection

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"

I am looking around for something in zend functions that could help to protect sql injection as well XSS protection.

Please let me know if there is any function or technique in zend framework?

Exmaple sql code

```
$users->update($data, 'id=1');
```

and

```
$content = new Application_Model_Content();
$params = $this->_request->getParams('id');
$where = "id = '" . $params['id'] . "'";
$content->delete($where);
```

Comment: "Exmaple sql code" --- there is not even a single character about sql there.

Comment: It is in a way we use in zend framework.

Comment: it's not. It's a php code.

Comment: Question is simple i am looking around to protect XSS in zend framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that by pasing array, not string as an argument to delete method:

```
$db->delete('content', array(
    'id' = ?' => $this->_request->getParams('id'),
));
```

or specification said that:

```
$content = new Application_Model_Content();
$row = $content->fetchRow(array('id'=>$this->_request->getParams('id')));

// DELETE this row
$row->delete();
```

You can also escape params by zend methods:

```
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM t WHERE myname = ?", $inputlike);
```

Comment: those two examples take care about xss and other kinds of incjections automatically.

Comment: @Piotr Pasich: "those two examples take care about xss" --- they don't. You don't realize the difference between sql injections and xss do you?

Comment: In this case what can be the solution?

Comment: Escaping the string from html special chars.